# How do I create imap checker that reads from csv file and loop for each line using multithreading?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, imap

The script only checks the first 10 lines of csv file, I want the script to iterate over all the lines of the file using threads to speed up the process.

Code:

```
import time
import csv
import imaplib
from threading import Thread


combo = []
FileToOpen = open("emails.csv", "r")
csvDictReader = csv.DictReader(FileToOpen)
successEmail = open("SuccessEmails.txt", "a")
for email in csvDictReader:
    combo.append(email)
    rows_count = len(list(csvDictReader))

t1 = time.perf_counter()

combo_new = combo


def ConnectorImap(combo_new):
    for Email in combo_new:
        login = Email['login']
        password = Email['password']
        imap_serv = "imap." + login.split('@')[-1]
        mail_serv = "mail." + login.split('@')[-1]
        try:
               print(login,password,imap_serv)
               print('logging in as %s' % login)
               # create an IMAP4 class with SSL
               imap_ssl = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_serv)
               resp_code, response = imap_ssl.login(login,password)
               print(resp_code)
               if resp_code == "OK":
                  successEmail.write(login + ',' + password)
                  successEmail.write("\n")
               imap_ssl.logout()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            pass

threads = []

for idx, line in enumerate(rows_count):
    # We start one thread per url present.
    process = Thread(target=ConnectorImap, args=(combo_new))
    process.start()
    threads.append(process)
for process in threads:
    process.join()

t2 = time.perf_counter()
print(f'finished in{t2 - t1} seconds')
```

I am new to python please any help! I want the script to iterate over all the lines of the file using threads to speed up the process.

Comment: try to understan what are you doing

Comment: thanks for your comment , i am new to python would you please point to what I'm doing wrong or give me some advices.